# Is it possible to perform string processing in prolog

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

I want to perform some operation like string search, iterate, split etc on sentence. I checked couple of Prolog tuts but no  help - http://kti.ms.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/contents.html, http://www.bitwisemag.com/copy/programming/prolog/intro/firststeps.html. I wanted to write program like this :

```
for linking in post_script_link_list:
        sub_link = re.search('\((.*?)\)',linking).group(1)
        if sub_link in links_list1:         
            if ('Who').lower() in sent_split or 'Who' in sent_split:
                result = 'person'
                break
            elif (('Where').lower() in sent_split or 'Where' in sent_split) and 'What' not in read_str and 'what' not in read_str:
                result = 'location'
                break
            elif ('Why').lower() in sent_split or 'Why' in sent_split:
                result = 'reason'
                break
            elif ('How many').lower() in read_str or 'How many' in read_str:
                result = 'count'
                break
            elif (('When').lower() in sent_split or 'When' in sent_split) and 'What' not in read_str and 'what' not in read_str:
                result = 'time'
                break
            elif (('How').lower() in sent_split or 'How' in sent_split) and ('How long').lower() not in read_str and 'How long' not in read_str and ('How much').lower() not in read_str and 'How much' not in read_str:
                result = 'manner'
                break
        elif sub_link in links_list2:
            check_yn = verify_yesno(post_script_link_list)
            if check_yn == 1:
                result = 'Yes/No'
                break
            elif check_yn == 0:
                result = 'Not found'
                break
            break
        else:
            result = 'Not found'
```

is it possible to perform usnig prolog? I am using pyswip and python

**UPDATE**

```
1 ?- split_string("a.b.c.d", ".", "", L).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: split_string/4 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use prolog? What is wrong with what you have? Do you have any experience with prolog or other functional programming languages?

Comment: @VincentBeltman: Yes, I have little experience with prolog, where there were simple rules, which was fine. While working on rules based system, it become simple to manage using prolog. In case of python, every time need to edite code and add if ... else and code become too nested, complicated

Comment: I see a lot of enhancements for your code. I could clean it up a little. Or you could post your code on code review.

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog, there is also "strings": http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings The predicates on "strings" are a bit closer in semantics to what you are trying to achieve than atom and code list predicates. This won't make your work much easier, though, it seems you rather have a problem with organizing your thoughts.

Comment: @VincentBeltman: I appreciate if suggest cleaning @ https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/76956/pytho-code-for-rules-based-system

Comment: Are you talking about string processing, or more generally, natural language processing? Or what is the bigger picture? There are some known patters for NLP in Prolog. As far as avoiding addition of lots of `if-else` constructs in Python, you might consider a more data driven approach rather than and *ad hoc* approach to scanning for and acting on words.

Comment: @luker: yes, for NLP. Rules keep varying and increasing, I appreciate if you suggest if any 'library or package' for NLP in prolog exist. Bigger picture here is `identifying the answer type` for input query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a string contains a particular substring, you can use `append/3` or `sub_atom/5`, depending how you represent your string.

If your strings are atoms, use `sub_atom/5`:

```
substring(Atom, Substring):-
    sub_atom(Atom, _, _, _, Substring).

?- substring('... Where is that?', 'Where').
true ;
false.
```

If your strings are lists of codes, use `append/3`:

```
substring(Codes, Substring):-
    append(S, _, Codes),
    append(_, Substring, S).

?- substring(".. Where is that?", "Where").
true ;
false.
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I could not understand difference between both. And is there any way to split sentence and iterate for each word?

Comment: There's [`split_string/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=split_string/4) in SWI Prolog.

Comment: That is because `split_string/4` is available since version 7.

Comment: If you need to implement such a predicate, it's better to post a different question in order to keep questions and answers simple and useful for others too.